# What problem does kin selection solve?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, fitness, philosophy-of-science

I'm trying to understand what problem led to a development of kin selection.

The explanations I've found consist roughly of the following:

> The existence of some altruistic and cooperative behaviors in social
>   insects like honey bees, the phenomenon of sterile castes formed by
>   non-reproductive individuals that leave no offspring and the suicidal
>   role of these insects in defending the hive, were traits that natural
>   selection could not favor. [Kin Selection | Nectunt](http://nectunt.bifi.es/to-learn-more-overview/kin-selection/)

What I do not understand: Why could natural selection not favor the phenomenon of sterile castes?

From the perspective of the sterile worker: Since it can't reproduce, no strategy will affect the number of offspring it has (will always be 0). So there is no conflict with natural selection.

From the perspective of the queen bee: Her offspring consist of sterile worker bees and a new fertile queen bee. The worker bees improve the viability of the next queen bee. This is consistent with natural selection.

Therefore, I can't see the relevance of the worker bee sharing lots of genes with its sister queen bee. This seems to be nothing but an ancillary effect of the mechanisms of evolutionary change. 
Imagine, the queen bee could produce worker bees without a genome (like a robot), or a genome that is not related to its sister queen bee, those worker bees would still show altruistic behavior.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why natural selection leads to selfishness

Imagine a population of individuals. At a given locus, some individual carry the `A` allele and some others can the `S` allele (`A` for altruistic and `S` for Selfish). For simplicity, we will assume organisms are haploid. Individuals carrying the `S` allele are selfish and will take care of themselves only. The `A` allele are altruistic meaning that they produce behaviours (and non-behavioural phenotypes) that will reduce their fitness and increase the fitness of other individuals in the population.

As the altruistic behave as to reduce their fitness, they will be at a selective disadvantage and therefore, over time, only selfish individuals will remain.

## How can altruism evolve then?

The study of the the evolution (and evolutionary consequences) of behaviour (and non-behavioural phenotypes) that affect the fitness of other individuals in the population is called [social evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_evolution). Social evolution is a wide field of knowledge and I will here attempt a very short summary of it so many concepts will be left out!

There are two main (non-exclusive) ways by which altruism can evolve:

- Repeated interactions (False altruism)
- Kin interactions (True altruism)

**Repeated interactions**

The concept is grounded within [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory). A good introduction to game theory is definitely out of the scope of this question but I just want to give a little bit of an intuition. I will over-simplified the concepts of game theory but you should definitely have a look at it. Those concepts are very enlightening for questions of evolutionary biology, economy, psychology, sociology and even philosophy.

If for example, the altruistic individuals are actually only altruistic to those
that have shown altruism in the past (via a **Tit-for-Tat** strategy for example or through the use of **reputation**), then altruistic individuals may end up have a higher fitness than the selfish individuals. Imagine for example that selfish individuals give nothing and receive nothing. Let's assume that all altruistic individuals, all make one good deed and receive one good deed. Giving a good deed comes at a **cost** of having, say 0.8 fewer offsprings on average. Receiving a good deed comes at a **benefit** of 1.2 extra offsprings. Overall and on average, each altruistic individual will produce 0.4 more offsprings than the selfish individuals and therefore, over time the whole population will become altruistic.

We often refer to these concepts as false altruism because altruistic individuals actually has a fitness increase over their life time. Let's now talk about true altruism where altruistic individuals really just give without receiving but yet, the allele coding for altruism thrives.

**Kin interactions**

Note first that any kin interaction follows within a give game theory scenario. As such kin interaction is just an add-on on what I discussed earlier. For those used to Hamilton's rule, please note that Hamilton's rule apply to **Prisoner's dilemna** (a type of game theory scenario) only.

So, imagine now that altruistic individuals are being altruistic with their family members (their **kins**) only (either because they direct their altruism or because there is a strong **population structure**). Note that such altruistic behaviour can pretty indirect as helping your partner (who we will assume is not part of your close family) will have for consequence that your partner may offer better parental care and therefore by being altruistic to your partner, you are actually being altruistic to you offsprings (which are your kins).

Because the kins of altruistic individuals probably carry the `A` allele, eve if the altruistic individual is experiencing a lifetime cost in fitness, the `A` allele may still thrive and the recipients of this altruism are likely also carrying the `A` allele. In other words, a truly altruistic individual is an individual that sacrifice itself for helping the allele `A` present in its kins to thrive. In yet other words, true altruism is when an allele is ensuring that copies of itself present in other individual will manage to get passed on.

And this is called **Kin Selection**. I can now clearly answer your question

## Your question

> What problem does kin selection solve?

Kin selection explains "true altruism"!

Only "true altruism" can yield to such separation of the reproductive task as that some individuals are perfectly steriles. In your post, you say

> From the perspective of the sterile worker: Since it can't reproduce, no strategy will affect the number of offspring it has (will always be 0)

What is missing from this logic is that, 1) at a time workers could still reproduce and 'gave it up' and 2) in many (maybe most?) social species (honeybees, termites, ants and also in non-hymenopteran eusocial species), workers are still able to sometimes reproduce and are also able to overthrow the queen.

Comment: Found this: http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/282/1803/20142886
"helpers do not necessarily improve their inclusive fitness by foregoing reproduction. These findings suggest the earliest evolutionary steps towards eusociality are most favored if mediated through maternal manipulation.“
That’s what I mean, if this can be achieved my maternal manipulation, then it seems to me to follow, that relatedness isn’t absolutely necessary. 
But I’m starting to realize that I asked too broadly and should first read some papers. If I then still don’t get it, I'll post a follow up question.

Answer (score 1):

Kin selection explains a violation of the assumption that individuals will always selfishly promote their own reproduction. (Lemmings jumping into the sea is a myth that does not happen). Every ***individual*** is supposed to work toward sending its own genes into the next generation. In your example, you say that the queen should just pump out workers to serve herself. And she does. But the workers are individuals too, with their own genes, and theoretically, should be selfish. However, in this case, due to honeybee reproduction and haplodiploidy, the workers are more than 50% related to their siblings. The math works out such that working toward the success of the colony is a more efficient strategy for promoting worker genes than if the workers were to try to reproduce on their own. Remember that one point in evolutionary time, these workers were reproductively capable, and gave up their own reproduction to serve the colony. So I think that what you are missing is that at some point in time, workers were once capable of reproduction, and gave it up. They were not always cogs in a machine.

Comment: "But the workers are individuals too, with their own genes, and theoretically, should be selfish." -> I addressed that: They are sterile, so the cost of their "sacrifice" is 0, which is consistent with selfishness.

Comment: "workers were once capable of reproduction, and gave it up." From the little I know, it doesn't like they were the ones who gave it up. It's more like it was taken from them.

Comment: They were not always sterile. They evolved from ancestors that were fertile. This is what breaks the rule.

Comment: It was not a conscious decision. Kin selection explains the math, and how such behavior could evolve without breaking assumptions about selfish reproduction.

Comment: And no, reproduction was not taken from them. Their genes still go forward into the next generation more efficiently than if they were laying their own eggs. It is a kind of decoupling of the individual from reproduction.

Comment: Both the worker bee and the queen bee evolved from the same ancestors. Natural selection started to favor individual bees that additionally laid offspring that behaved altruistically. 
You say, every individual is supposed to selfishly promote its own reproduction. Yes, but only in accordance to its own power.
If I’m not mistaken, the behavior of a bee is genetically determined. So it’s outside the power of that bee to have more reproduction and the rule isn’t broken (only if you ascribe free will to the worker bee).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71279/discussion-between-karl-kjer-and-mathias).

Comment: @KarlKjer Unlike you said "individuals will always selfishly" is NOT an assumption. It is a consequence of NS.

Comment: Individuals always acting selfishly to promote their own genes is absolutely an assumption that comes from natural selection, and is violated under the conditions we are talking about. Assumptions are fundamental units of refutation science. Things that are a consequence of a theory are still assumptions.

Comment: Well... I disagree with your definition of 'assumption'. If the consequences of all our models were to be called assumptions, then outside of the data themselves, nothing in science would not be an assumption which sounds pretty wrong. I am used to call an assumption, a belief that is not supported by evidences (or at least not necessarily always true in all cases found in nature)  on which a model is based. For example, HWr is based on an assumption of infinite population. However, the allele to genotypes frequencies resulting from the model is not an assumption.